# Controller action with params returns 404 not found

Tags: php, yii, controller, http-status-code-404

I'm using Yii and I have a Controller named `User` and some actions for CRUD-operations. I have added a new action as follows:

```
public function actionEmbedded($field, $action, $id){
    /* code */
}
```

To access this action the url should be

```
/user/embedded/field/logins/action/view/id/5542ab0cb0db0ab000000001
```

But this returns a `404 Not found error`.

**However** when I change one of the parameters to `$_id` instead of `$id` ...

```
public function actionEmbedded($field, $action, $_id){
    /* code */
}
```

... it is possible to access the action just like expected

```
/user/embedded/field/logins/action/view/_id/5542ab0cb0db0ab000000001
```

Any ideas why? Is any of my parameter names reserved? I do use the `$id` in other actions, if that might be a reason to this behaviour.

**UPDATE:**
Here's the urlManager-code from my config.php file.

```
    'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'showScriptName'=> false,
        'rules'=>array(
            // Handles differen API versions
            'api/1.0/<action:\w+>/*' => 'api_1_0_/<action>',
            array('api_1_1_/<action>', 'pattern'=>'api/1.1/<action:\w+>', 'verb' => 'GET'),
            //array('api_1_1_/Post<action>', 'pattern'=>'api/1.1/<action:\w+>/*', 'verb' => 'POST'),

            // User specific API calls (starts with users/me)
            array('api_1_1_/prices', 'pattern'=>'api/1.1/prices/<market:\w+>/<biddingArea:\w+>/hour/<period:\w+>', 'verb' => 'GET'),
            array('api_1_1_/view/model/users/id/me', 'pattern'=>'api/1.1/users/me', 'verb' => 'GET'),
            array('api_1_1_/listEmbeddedArray/model/users/id/me/array/contracts', 'pattern'=>'api/1.1/users/me/meters', 'verb' => 'GET'),
            array('api_1_1_/view/model/units/id/<id>', 'pattern'=>'api/1.1/users/me/meters/<id:\w+>', 'verb' => 'GET'),
            //array('api_1_1_/viewEmbeddedArray/model/users/id/me/array/contracts/ean/<ean>', 'pattern'=>'api/1.1/users/me/meters/<source:\w+>/<ean:\w+>', 'verb' => 'GET'),
            //array('api_1_1_/series', 'pattern'=>'api/1.1/users/me/meters/<source:\w+>/<ean:\w+>/series/<query:\w+>', 'verb' => 'GET'),
            //array('api_1_1_/series/source/<source>/ean/<ean>/resolution/<resolution>/query<query>', 'pattern'=>'api/1.1/users/me/meters/<source:\w+>/<ean:\w+>/series/<resolution:\w+>/<query:\w+>', 'verb' => 'GET'),
            //array('api_1_1_/view/model/unit/id/<id>', 'pattern'=>'api/1.1/users/me/meters/<id:\w+>', 'verb' => 'GET'),
            array('api_1_1_/series/id/<id>', 'pattern'=>'api/1.1/users/me/series/<id:\w+>', 'verb' => 'GET'),

            array('api_1_1_/list', 'pattern'=>'api/1.1/users/me/<model:\w+>', 'verb' => 'GET'),
            array('api_1_1_/view', 'pattern'=>'api/1.1/users/me/<model:\w+>/<id:\w+>', 'verb' => 'GET'),
            array('api_1_1_/delete', 'pattern'=>'api/1.1/users/me/<model:\w+>/<id:\w+>', 'verb' => 'DELETE'),

            // General API calls
            array('api_1_1_/download', 'pattern'=>'api/1.1/download/<model:\w+>', 'verb' => 'GET'),
            array('api_1_1_/series', 'pattern'=>'api/1.1/<model:\w+>/<id:\w+>/series', 'verb' => 'GET'),

            array('api_1_1_/listEmbeddedArray', 'pattern'=>'api/1.1/<model:\w+>/<id:\w+>/<array:\w+>', 'verb' => 'GET'),
            array('api_1_1_/updateEmbeddedArray', 'pattern'=>'api/1.1/<model:\w+>/<id:\w+>/<array:\w+>/<ean:\w+>', 'verb' => 'PUT'),
            array('api_1_1_/deleteEmbeddedArray', 'pattern'=>'api/1.1/<model:\w+>/<id:\w+>/<array:\w+>/<ean:\w+>', 'verb' => 'DELETE'),
            array('api_1_1_/viewEmbeddedArray', 'pattern'=>'api/1.1/<model:\w+>/<id:\w+>/<array:\w+>/<ean:\w+>', 'verb' => 'GET'),
            array('api_1_1_/createEmbeddedArray', 'pattern'=>'api/1.1/<model:\w+>/<id:\w+>/<array:\w+>', 'verb' => 'POST'),

            array('api_1_1_/list', 'pattern'=>'api/1.1/<model:\w+>', 'verb' => 'GET'),

            array('api_1_1_/view', 'pattern'=>'api/1.1/<model:\w+>/<id:\w+>', 'verb' => 'GET'),
            array('api_1_1_/update', 'pattern'=>'api/1.1/<model:\w+>/<id:\w+>', 'verb' => 'PUT'),
            array('api_1_1_/delete', 'pattern'=>'api/1.1/<model:\w+>/<id:\w+>', 'verb' => 'DELETE'),
            array('api_1_1_/create', 'pattern'=>'api/1.1/<model:\w+>', 'verb' => 'POST'),

        ),
    ),
```

Comment: You seem to be using the url manager or something, or else your url would look something like `/index.php?r=user/embedded&id=5542ab0cb0db0ab000000001`. How are you accessing your action with that type of url?

Comment: Yes I use urlManager. I tried to turn it off and used `/index.php?r=user/embedded&id=525ec506df6232341c000033&field=logins&action=view` but it caused the same issues...

Comment: could you please post the urlmanager code?

Comment: I updated my question with the urlmanager code.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot comment, so I'll post this as an answer even though it is not; check your urlManager rules, there is probably a pattern in your urlManager rules in which your request fits, and the framework tries to execute it. If I recall correctly, the default rule for view expects the parameter `$id` and thus, your application may or may not be trying to call `userController::actionView($id)`, which does not exist, because of a rule that looks like `'<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view'` in your configuration.

But that is only a guess, I recommend you turn on debug and check where the application is trying to go. You probably could fix that by changing the view rule to module/controller/view instead of controller/view in your urlManager configuration.

Cheers.

Comment: That is a good point! I checked my urlManager rules but they all start with "api/1.1/..." so guess they should not affect any requests starting with "user/..."?